# PayPal PayFlow - converting existing transaction into Recurring Payment Profile

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I'm a bit confused about PayPal Payflow Recurring Billing

I read in the documentation that I can convert an existing transaction into a recurring payment profile.

This means that I can send my user to the ExpressCheckout page where she makes a "zero dollar" *one time* transaction, and then, PayPal sends me back the transaction ID (PNREF) which I can use as ORIGID value when I'm creating the new profile?

And if its correct, it means that I don't have to handle credit card and other sensitive information, because basically the user types her details on the PayPal hosted checkout page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a completed transaction to create a recurring billing profile, but it cannot be an auth transaction (zero dollars or otherwise). Quote from the documentation:

> IMPORTANT: You can use only a Sale or Delayed Capture transaction as a
>   template for a profile.

https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf

Comment: What would the alternative be if the current billing profile does not have a transaction yet?  Is there a way to copy the information from an existing profile to a new profile?